# How to screen capture browsers bookmark dropdown menu?

Tags: screenshot

#### How to capture a chrome browser bookmark bar dropdown menu showing the icons (favicons) and names of bookmarks within it ?

In my chrome browser I use bookmarks and also bookmark **folders** that have bookmarks within them.
Like this:

[image]

This is about capturing how one of those *folders* looks that has 8 bookmarks within it looks when the folder is clicked on and shows all the bookmarks inside it.  I want to capture how the dropdown looks (mainly to see all the different favicons in my case).
If I use the delay feature and then use the dropdown it simply isn't captured after the time delay and the menu is still open.
More seververely, if I use the mouse and click open the menu first and then proceed to use shift-print screen it actually crashes my desktop environment and now, for example, all windows pane headers show the cross hair but I can't 'escape' in any way.  I currently use the keyboard ctrl-alt-delete approach to logout to and back in to fix this. Yuch.

I've tried printscreen window and print by area and the delays but none of this helped.  The delays worked but did not then capture the dropdown which I had open when the screenshot took place.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My preferred tool is called [Shutter](https://shutter-project.org/).

First, you need to install it, as it's not installed by default. It is in some default repositories, but I am not sure where the cutoff is or if it's in the latest releases. Try:

```
sudo apt install shutter
```

If that doesn't work, then try this:

```
sudo add-apt-repository -y ppa:linuxuprising/shutter
sudo apt update
sudo apt install -y shutter
```

Once installed, open Shutter. In the lower left, you'll see that you can use a delay. Set the delay to suit your needs, choose to show the cursor or not, and pick your style of screenshot.

In this case, I chose to screenshot 'Desktop' with a 5 second delay and then edited it down:

[image: bookmarks screenshot]

If you want, you can even [edit from within Shutter](https://itsfoss.com/shutter-edit-button-disabled/), though that takes a bit of work. The directions may change, so that link will work for the time being. It's not overly complex.

You can also choose to 'export' your images. You can configure your own FTP site, or use a few online services, both with authentication and without.

Comment: I installed shutter and it was unusable.  Options are grayed ouit and top menu lists them but they don't do anything when selected.

Comment: Can you be more specific? It'd be a shame if it doesn't work. It's my favorite of all screenshot utilities. If it does NOT work, most other screenshot apps have a delay feature. You should edit your initial question to let us know what flavor of Ubuntu and version number you're using.

Comment: yeah its wierd that I use the menu options and just nothing happens.  Ubuntu 20 and updated my system today.  odd.  I did discov er a workaroud however by using the delay with a WHOLE screen screenshot.  For some reason that allowed the open browser menu to be captured whereas window capture did not.  I was then... able to subsequently that screenshot (!) and extract the piece I needed using rectangular shpae select for one more screenshot

Comment: I just tested it with Ubuntu 20.04.1 and it's working properly here. I didn't even have to install anything new to enable the editing feature, unlike Shutter on 18.04. I'd try a simple reboot and then loading it from the terminal to see what errors it throws up. It may be a bit old, but it remains my preferred screenshot tool. I use it multiple times on most days. What happens if you right click the icon in the activity section once Shutter is open?

Comment: I quit the program and reran it and it then worked,  yeah it's a bit odd how you select and then press return and then use the dropdown and then the delay kicks in. but yes that worked. thanks.

Comment: Glad you got it sorted. It has a ton of features, so it'll take you a while to discover them all or find uses for them all. Good luck!

Answer (score 1):

Like this?

[image: 1]

I've done that screen shot with the "xfce4-screenshooter" (which is part of Xubuntu but should be installable on gnome as well.)

I set the "Delay before capturing" to three seconds, selected a region and after selecting it I clicked on the menu/folder icon so it dropped down. Not the most elegant way, since you have to figure out your area without exactly knowing the extend, but it works.

Comment: This is what my Ubuntu has already installed and the problem is I can't leave the menu open, or use the delay and then click to open it as that takes the shot.  It seems doable but with my ubuntu (20) seems not achievable for me. obvf u could from your screenshot

Answer (score 1):

just run in terminal or set a ubuntu shortcut ley (power key, 'keyboard shortcuts' , custom  as

```
gnome-screenshot -d 10
```

-d if for a delay of 10 seconds.

then go and bring up the menu and wait for it.

gnome-screenshot --help

-w -a -a might be useful

Answer (score 0):

### Workaround

The (regular which is also the xcfe) 'window capture', even with delay, didn't allow me to have the folder menu open.

However... a full screen capture (with delay) did let me open the browser window bookmark menu and capture it correctly.

Then I make a screenshot of that screenshot to cut out the piece I needed (the menu showing a dropdown). which i put on the right on some unfurl menus I wanted as shown below.

Voila: (dropdown menu on the right of the image)

[image]